# How to solve import error from mesa.visualization.UserParam?

Tags: python, mesa, mesa-abm

```
Import error: cannot import name 'UserSettableParameter' from 'mesa.visualization.UserParam'
```

- [pip list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5kJk7.png)
- [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QZHY9.png)
- [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AqGav.png)

I Checked Conda list and pip list, both of them have mesa installed and tried several times to installed and uninstalled mesa, but still has error. I use python 3.10 and Mesa 2.1.1.
Can anyone help with it ?

The code is from https://github.com/hildobby/fire-suppression-abm
I hope to run the code but it keeps give me errors

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to my research [here](https://github.com/projectmesa/mesa-viz-tornado/blob/main/mesa_viz_tornado/UserParam.py), there is no `UserSettableParameter` where you are importing.

As of [2.0.0](https://github.com/projectmesa/mesa/releases/tag/v2.0.0#:%7E:text=UserSettableParameter(%5B%27number%27%2C%20%27slider%27%2C%27checkbox%27%2C%20%27choice%27%2C%20%27StaticText%27%5D)%3A%20convert%20to%20NumberInput%20%2C%20Slider%2C%20CheckBox%2C%20Choice%2C%20StaticText) `UserSettableParameter` has been deprecated. and moved to `NumberInput` , `Slider`, `CheckBox`, `Choice`, `StaticText`.

> UserSettableParameter(['number', 'slider','checkbox', 'choice', 'StaticText']): convert to NumberInput , Slider, CheckBox, Choice, StaticText